# How animate UIView height constraint in Swift programmatically without making an IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have created a button which is attached to the top, leading and trailing and has fixed height. And when I'm tapping the button the new UIView instance should appear with animation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var topButton = UIButton()
var myView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    topButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    topButton.setTitle("Add Acctivity", for: .normal)
    topButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    topButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    topButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 26)
    topButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(topButton)

    topButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    topButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    topButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    topButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

}

@objc func expandMenu() {

   myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}



}
```

[image: Nothing is working even I put the height to be 300]

And the interesting thing is when I'm putting the height smaller than its initial value the animation works.

[image]

I saw many tutorials when people are creating IBOutlet from storyboard and then changing its constant value. But I'm wondering how to do that programmatically.

Comment: Before tackling your problem, why don't you want to use Outlets/IB?

Comment: You can achieve this with IBOutlet. I'm wondering why you don't want to do that!

Comment: I'm not sure how to that in the code... I saw some examples when a button was created in storyboard then IBOutlet is created from buttons height constraint. But in my example, everything is in code.

Comment: So, to make sure that I got your point, `myView` should be 100 points height by default, and when tapping the button its height should be 300, correct?

Comment: Correct, Ahmed.

Comment: Another thought: how about letting the default height for it to be 300 and changing its y-axis instead? :)

Comment: It will work, but I need to change the height.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are trying to *reactivate* another constraint that describes the height of `myView`, by saying (in `expandMenu()`):

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

I would assume that you are getting a runtime warning similar to:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400008e5b0 UIView:0x7fa16a419450.height == 100   (active)>",
>       "NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000097e30 UIView:0x7fa16a419450.height == 300   (active)>"
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

means that `myView` already has a constraint for height, which is (in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

---

What you should do instead is to change the `constant` value of the same constraint instead. You could achieve it like this:

Declare a `NSLayoutConstraint` as instance variable:

```
var myViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
myViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 100)
myViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
```

instead of:

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Finally, in `expandMenu()`:

```
myViewHeightConstraint.constant = 300
```

instead of:

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Furthermore:**

If you are aiming to let the same button to achieve the expand/collapse behavior, you would need to simply implement it as (in `expandMenu()`):

```
myViewHeightConstraint.constant = myViewHeightConstraint.constant == 300 ? 100 : 300
```

Comment: cool cool, it worked, but why I need to have a reference? is there any method to change constant value without making a reference variable?

Comment: @Tigran you could consider that working with a constraint is similar to working with any IBOutlet, it has to has a reference because you cannot add more than one constraint for the same anchor, you have to edit the existed one (Roughly speaking, at some point you are trying to add more than one constraint to tell what's the height of the view, which makes conflict).

Answer (score 1):

The [`constraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension/1500941-constraint) method returns an `NSLayoutConstraint`. You can assign it to a class level variable:

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...

    heightConstraint = myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

And then you will have a property `heightConstraint` that is very much like an `IBOutlet`. You can animate this the same way you animate an `IBOutlet` constraint.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I why it doesn't work when I'm changing the value without reference variable

myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

Comment: @Tigran Because you are changing another different constraint in `expandMenu`. With a reference variable, you make sure you are modifying the same constraint.